# Modal Contact Form - Shopify

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, shopify, contact-form, simplemodal

I've built a modal contact form, but when user hit the submit button, the modal closes. I want the modal to stay open so users can see the success message.
I see there's this code in my CSS file... But if I take that out, then the modal will show on the page at all times.

> .mfp-hide {
>     display: none !important; }

Comment: Does the modal just close, or does the whole page refresh? Are you using javascript to submit the form?

Comment: It's an inline modal (I believe that's what it's called). The page refreshes when the submit button is clicked. So I guess the modal is not what I need to edit...it's the function of the submit button? That would be in my JS file right? 
Here is where it is: shopbarkrangers.com/pages/faqs

Comment: You will have to submit the form using Ajax https://gist.github.com/rickydazla/45a3c719cfb498997d7b

Comment: Ohh I see. I will look into that. Thank you!